# Use proxy for http request in browser showing " This should be possible with php and CGI proxies which handles"

Tags: http, web, proxy, network-programming

I'm trying use a proxy to load a http request such as this:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080?url=http://mysite.com
```

but I'm getting this error:

> There is a loop in network for HTTP traffic. Check your network
>   topology and proxy & firewall configuration

Does anyone know what's wrong with the request or how can I modify the request in such a way that I don't have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a MikroTik HttpProxy. http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Proxy

I don't believe it supports the `?url=blah` syntax.

Try configuring your browser to use the proxy ip:port for all traffic, then attempt your url.

If you are using php + curl, use the `CURLOPT_PROXY` option for ip:port proxies.

HideMyAss has a free web proxy service that you could use:
http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy/

They have a massive ip:port proxy list and their pro vpn rocks too - something like 40k unique ips.